# Difference between とかの + noun and とか + noun

Tags: particles, particle-の

I recently bumped into these two sentences

> サッカーとか野球**とか**スポーツをする
>
> 'テニスとかサッカーとかアメフト**とかの**球技が大好きだからね

Which I noticed is that they are very similar and in the latter, after 「とか」we find the particle 「の」. What I want to know is if we could rewrite again these sentences, the former with the particle 「の」and the latter without it as follows:

> 'サッカーとか野球**とかの**スポーツをする
>
> 'とかサッカーとかアメフト**とか**球技が大好きだからね

Which is the nuance of the particle 「の」in these exemples? What is the difference between using the particle and not using it?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of nuance they are pretty much indistinguishable, but とかの is colloquial. A teacher might correct it to とか if you use it in a written assignment etc.